# Procedure entry point could not be located in exe

Tags: c++, windows, dll, runtime-error

I have a `exe` that I built on Windows using `mingw-gcc`. It has several dependencies. All of them are located on the `PATH`. However, when I run it I get the following error.

`The procedure entry point _ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS could not be located in the dynamic link library <name_of_exe>`

I have looked at similar questions and they suggested using `__declspec(dllimport)` but those questions the dynamic link library in question is actually a `dll` and not an `exe`. Do I need to trawl through my dependencies and add each one as a `__declspec(dllimport)` or something?

Comment: I can't demangle `_ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS`, are you sure you have copy message properly? Anyway looks like wrong version of library has been loaded that is why this symbol can't be located.

Comment: The `_ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS` -- is that your function?  If not, then it has nothing to do with your executable.  It more than likely has to do with some other external library (MingW related) that is being loaded, and that function being called doesn't exist.

Comment: You can use the `nm` tool on your object files, to figure out where the `_ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS` symbol is coming from.  Then you can figure out what that source file is doing.

Comment: I did copy it correctly. Not sure why it cannot be demangled.  It seems to be std::logic_error when I grep the files.  I will use `nm` on some files and update this thank you!

Comment: This is the result of using `nm`:                                                                `0000000141634dbc I __imp__ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS_
0000000140a760b8 T _ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS_`  what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the entry point name is the name of a function or class method with some decoration. I think you are missing some dll or in the path you have some not updated version of the dll. The first thing to do is to search your project for anything like St11logic_error. This way you'll find the dll which is not updated then check the one on your exe path to be sure that it's the rigth one

Comment: This is most probably [std::logic_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error), but http://demangler.com/ can't decode it.

Comment: I greped the files and it is std::logic_error. I am depending on `libstdc++-6.dll` which I would guess is declaring it. What can I do about a reference in std not being found?

Comment: I got this in the output of `nm` `__imp__ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS_` in addition to the `ZNSt11logic_errorC2EOS_` and demangler confirmed that it is std::logic_error

Comment: I am using bazel 5.0 with `compiler=mingw-gcc` and I tried using `-static-libstdc++` and it doesn't seem to respect that option. So I am guessing I am stuck with using a dynamic link of stdc++. Should I just replace the uses of std::logic_error with some other exception? Does it have any benefits?

Comment: Also how do I find the `dll` that is being used? I found the `libstdc++-6.dll` and deleted it to see if it was the right one based on the ouput of `ldd` but then I kept getting the same error. I also tried replacing `logic_error` with `runtime_error` and the error message just changed to reflect that change.

Comment: Okay I solved it. You need to add `-static` to the linker options.